# libgdx - getButtonTable() missing Window method

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm following some [tutorial](http://pixelscientists.com/wordpress/?p=19) to create my own Inventory for my game. I have met with an insidious problem:

```
public class InventoryActor extends Window {
    public InventoryActor(Inventory inventory, DragAndDrop dragAndDrop, Skin skin) {
        super("Inventory", skin);

        // add an "X" button to the top right of the window, and make it hide the inventory
        TextButton closeButton = new TextButton("X", skin);
        closeButton.addListener(new HidingClickListener(this));
        getButtonTable().add(closeButton).height(getPadTop());

        // basic layout
        setPosition(400, 100);
        defaults().space(8);
        row().fill().expandX();
...
}
```

Everything in this code is neat and nice. There's one BUT -

```
getButtonTable().add(closeButton).height(getPadTop());
```

This method isn't implemented anywhere. Tutorial I'm following comes from 2014. Therefore I assume that it may be some deprecated/old method from Window class or something like that. 
My question is - is there any way I could repair it, and how can I add this 'X' close button to the window then? Should I use some other method?
Regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're extending from the wrong class; extend from `Dialog` instead of `Window`. Dialog is a subclass of Window with much more functionality.

Dialog also has a few convenience methods such as `Dialog button(String text)` and `Dialog text(String text)` that automatically separates text and buttons appropriately and makes creating simple popups really easy.

The entire documentation can be found [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html).

Comment: Indeed! I've missed a fact that Dialog inherits from Window and was trying to do something with Table, unnecessarily. Now everything works properly. Thank you! :)